# Oracle fetching columns names does not retrieve the result in the same order everytime

Tags: sql, oracle

So, I use the following SQL command to fetch the name of all columns of a table, but I also wanted them to be returned in the order they were created, for example:

```
create table X{
  name varchar(255),
  number varchar(255),
  something varchar(255))
```

I'd like that the return list was: name - number - something; but I keep getting different results. sometimes in that order, sometimes in the opposite. I'd like a command that retrieves in the order of creation, or in the opposite, I don't want "sorts" by alphabetical order or something. This is the command I use:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'X'
```

Comment: Add `ORDER BY COLUMN_ID` at the end.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT column_name
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'X' 
ORDER BY COLUMN_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Idf you want to be sure of the order You could use

> COLUMN_ID   Sequence number of the column as created

```
SELECT column_name
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'X'
ORDER BY column_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question says that you don't want "sorts".  Tables are defined in the relational model as an *unordered* set of records.  If you want them in a specific order, you *must* specify an ORDER BY clause.  Without an ORDER BY the database returns records in whatever order it finds convenient.

If you wish to know the order of creation, you will need to store a datetime value for that time of creation in a column in the table.  Then, when you retrieve data from the table you must ORDER BY that value.

You could also try using a SEQUENCE value instead of a datetime, but those may or may not work as well with record churning.  (I have limited experience with Oracle SEQUENCEs.) Even then, however, you will still need an ORDER BY.